# Expecting specific data types in C

Tags: c

I'm attempting to finish a portion of a program but I can't seem to make sense of how to complete a simple problem. In order for the user to get to the next portion of the program they need to enter a value as a char, decimal, and hex. If they don't the control switches to another function.

I was hoping it would be as easy as

```
if(input != "%c %d %x") etc.
```

from what I'm reading it seems to be much more confusing than that and I can't seem to find an answer although I'm sure I overlooked an obvious one.

Edit:

```
int main() {
    char input[512];
    int n;
    user_id = (char *)malloc(100);

    printf("Type your user id\n");
    my_fgets(user_id, 100, stdin);
    printf("Input for phase 1\n");
    my_fgets(input, 512, stdin);
    phase_1(input);
    n = hash2(user_id);
    printf("Your number is %d\n", n);
}
```

---

```
void phase_2(char *input, int n)
{
    n = n + 100;
    if(input != "%c\n")
        explode_bomb();
}
```

Comment: Do all three values need to be the same, just in different representations, or are they difference values? Is `input` a string?

Comment: @dogbert all three values just need to be in different representations. I may just be missing something because I'm only working on one function of a larger program but i digress

Comment: What type is `input`? Is it a string, or an int/char/etc?

Comment: @dogbert input is a pointer to a character array

Comment: Could you show an example of `input`?

Comment: `int n = 0; sscanf(input, "%*c %*d %*x %n", &n); if (n > 0) puts("Success");` should do it.  Posting more of the details of your needs would enable a more complete answer.

Comment: @Schwern I put a few chunks of the program up for clarity. Sorry for the confusion I wanted to make sure I put up relevant info.

Comment: The value of a number is the same no matter what base it is in. So accept a char for all 3 inputs, make sure they are valid for each base type (no characters for decimal etc.), and then convert them to how you'd like to use them in your program.

Comment: @Martinn How do I go about accepting it as a char though? Like how do I make a conditional to only accept char, etc.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for posting the code, but what is really needed is an example of what you expect to be in `input`.

Comment: @chux Would it not be simpler to use the return value from `sscanf` rather than using `%n`?

Comment: @Schwern No.  `"%*c"` with a `*` does not contribute to the return value.  Neither do `%*d %*x`.  To know complete parsing occurred, need to detect something after those 3 specifiers. A change to `n` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an input function, which reads input into a string, then use isdigit() ischar() isxchar() to scan the string to find out what **type** the input is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you expect `input` to be something like this: `C 67 43`.  The character `C` along with its value in decimal and hex.  You need to write a function to parse this string and determine if it's correct.

First, the parsing.  You're on the right track.  What you need is [`sscanf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm).

```
char char_char;
unsigned int char_hex;
unsigned int char_int;

if( sscanf(input, "%c %u %x", &char_char, &char_int, &char_hex) < 3 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s doesn't look like what I want\n", input);
    return false;
}
```

I chose `unsigned int` because `%x` maps to an unsigned integer and `char` also can safely be compared with an unsigned integer.

Then all you need to do is check if the three values are the same.  `sscanf` has already converted the hex into an unsigned integer, and `char` can safely be compared to an unsigned integer.

```
if( char_int != char_hex ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%u and %u don't match\n", char_int, char_hex);
    return false;
}

if( char_int != char_char ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%u and %c don't match\n", char_int, char_char);
    return false;
}

return true;
```

Put it all together and wrap a function around it.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool check_input(const char *input) {
    char char_char;
    unsigned int char_int;
    unsigned int char_hex;

    if( sscanf(input, "%c %d %x", &char_char, &char_int, &char_hex) < 3 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s doesn't look like what I want\n", input);
        return false;
    }

    if( char_int != char_hex ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%u and %u don't match\n", char_int, char_hex);
        return false;
    }

    if( char_int != char_char ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%u and %c don't match\n", char_int, char_char);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

A better function won't print to stderr, but would instead set the error message via a passed in `char *`.

Comment: I think you're my hero

Comment: but this also makes me realize just how much i have to learn >.<

Comment: Using `"%c %u %x"` and checking against `3` does not detect extra text on the `input`.

Comment: hmmm yeah you're right. I tried adding another if statement for greater than but it didn't seem to help lol

Comment: @chux Yup! Depends on what the input is supposed to be and what the tolerances are.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test if a string complies with a given format, use `"*"` and `"%n"`.

The `*` still scans for text that matches the specifier, but suppresses saving and also does not add to the return value.

`"%n"` directs `*scanf()`  to save the number of `char` scanned so far.

By testing if `n > 0` and if `input[n]` is the end of the string, code can simple detect a matching format.

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(input, "%*c %*d %*x %n", &n);
if (n > 0 && input[n] == '\0') {
  puts("Success");
}
```